# .htaccess rewrite url showing 404 not found

Tags: .htaccess

i want to change this URL

```
domain.com/adsbycat/sub_category.php?category=car-and-buses&category_id=1&sub_category=Car
```

to

```
domain.com/car-and-buses/1/Car
```

i write this code to do this

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /domain.com/    
RewriteRule ^adsbycat/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ adsbycat/sub_category.php?category=$1&category_id=$2&sub_category=$3
```

but when i request for new URL it showing **404 not found**. please fix this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this rule in site root .htaccess to rewrite `domain.com/car-and-buses/1/Car`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/(.+)$ adsbycat/sub_category.php?category=$1&category_id=$2&sub_category=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```